# How to tell the operation caused page fault on intel CPU?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86

How could the page fault handler know that it is faulting for read or write operation? Any flag/status value for this indication?

Comment: The page fault error code contains a W/R bit, indicating whether the access was a write (1) or a read (0).

Answer (score 0):

The page fault handler should not be concerned whether, the page is being accessed as a result of a read() or write() operations. However, it only checks the vma the page belongs to and its availability, and it determines if its writeable or readable or executable when page fault occurs. This is achieved by verifying the validity of an access of an page, the page fault handler must search the vm-area list (or the AVL tree) for the vm-area that covers the page being accessed. If the vm-area exists and its access right flags (VM_READ, VM_WRITE, and VM_EXEC) permit the access, then the access is valid. Also you may be interested in other flags associate with [enum pageflag](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/page-flags.h)